# How can I remove the extra spaces between my output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the first code where printed my output in order:

```
 import csv
 import random
 import os.path


 def filename ():

     filename = 'filename.txt'
     with open ("filename.txt", "r") as data_file:

        for line in data_file.readlines():
           line = line.strip().split()
           print (line [0], line [1], line[2])
```

This was the output:

```
 1  63075384    0.781952678
 1  212549126   0.050216027
 2  35003118    0.027205438
 2  230357107   0.065453827
 3  77023025    0.098224352
 3  225622058   0.785312636
```

I then wanted to randomize my output. So here is the second code where I did that:

```
 import random
 with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    lines = list(fin)

 random.shuffle(lines)
 for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

Here is the output. Which adds an extra blank space between each line:

```
2   35003118    0.027205438

3   77023025    0.098224352

2   230357107   0.065453827

1   212549126   0.050216027

3   225622058   0.785312636

1   63075384    0.781952678
```

My desired output is:

```
2   35003118    0.027205438
3   77023025    0.098224352
2   230357107   0.065453827
1   212549126   0.050216027
3   225622058   0.785312636
1   63075384    0.781952678
```

How can I alter the second code shown above so that I can print my output without those extra blank spaces?

I know this may seem like a duplicate question but the fact is that I have searched online and I can not seem to find a solution to this problem. I am happy to clarify anything. Thank You.

Comment: Your first script uses `trim()`, which removes the newline at the end of the input lines. You're not doing this in the second program, so it prints that newline, and then `print()` adds its own newline.

Comment: @Barmar It uses `strip()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your lines contain a newline character at the end of them, so in this loop:

```
for line in lines:
    print (line)
```

it will print the newline in the `line` string. Simply strip `line` to remove the newline:

```
for line in lines:
    print (line.strip())
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
import random

with open('filename.txt') as fin:
    lines = list(fin)
    random.shuffle(lines)
    for line in lines:
        print(line, end='')
```

Setting `end=''` in `print()` avoids printing an extra new line.

See the [Python docs on `print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) for more information.

Comment: Helpful note: The reason why it was printing the newline characters is that `'\n'` is the default value for `end`.